# Chrome Extension - onAlarm event fired later than expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

**tl;dr:** chrome.alarms.create() lags by about 60000ms, any alternatives to using this to run some code after a certain amount of minutes?

I have setInterval() and setTimeout() in mind, but ideally the background script is set to not be persistent.

---

Hi there - Happy to be making my first post here. Did search the site before asking this question :)

**Some context:** I am putting together a simple timer app in the form of a Google Chrome extension. It is based on chrome.alarms.create() and onAlarm().

E.g. if the user sets the timer for 25 minutes (multiplying by 60000 for time in ms), an alarm gets created like this:

```
let alarmID = "timer-complete-alarm";
let target = 25 * 60000 + Date.now();
chrome.alarms.create(alarmID, { when: target });
```

And an onAlarm listener is registered:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(() => {
  // Send notification
});
```

**The issue:** I tested this extension thoroughly by loading it unpacked first, and this method was accurate when tested against a separate timer. The onAlarm listener would fire, log to the console, and send a notification. However, the released version in the Chrome Web Store lags by roughly about 60000ms.

[Creating the alarm with a 2 minute target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJbp1.png)
[The alarm fired 3 minutes after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDIgD.png)

According to the documentation, it is normal for this to occur:

> In order to reduce the load on the user's machine, Chrome limits alarms to at most once every 1 minute **but may delay them an arbitrary amount more**
>
> https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms

**My question:** Any ideas on why the alarm doesn't have a lag when testing it unpacked, and also, aside from setInterval() or setTimeout(), is there a more efficient way to initiate some code after many minutes?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you should use `alarms.create` with a time set at least 1m earlier than desired, then use `setTimeout` to get to the final time.

Comment: @Makyen - Thank you for the input. I tested this out, and even with only 1m left, the background script goes idle and `setTimeout` will not wake it up. Might end up making it `"persistent": true`.